# Чистая карта в android studio

Tags: android-studio, google-maps-api, kotlin

Создаю новый проект в android studio. 
Указываю что проект будет с картой google maps. 
Содаю ключ, указываю API KEY в переменной google_maps_key

Компилирую, запускаю в эмуляторе, но карта пустая.

На стороне гугла снял ограничение для этого ключа. 
Запустил Maps Android SDK.
Но, карта по прежнему пустая.

Подскажите куда смотреть? 
Где может быть ошибка?

Comment: Покажите логи, там должна быть подсказка.

Comment: какие именно логи?

Comment: Вашего приложения, вестимо.

Comment: Проблема была в ключе на стороне гугла.